# Hey how do I convert this JS into react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new in react and just struggling a bit to make it work properly.
So here is a snippet from JS file and I need to convert it react.

```
let squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");

 for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
   squares[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
     squares[i].classList.add("light");
     setTimeout(function () {
       squares[i].classList.remove("light");
     }, 800);
   });
 }
```

In that react component I have just some divs with className="square"

```
export default function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="row ">
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
      <div className="square"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with? Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a component for each square.

Return a JSX div from it.

Create a state in that component for `light` (default it to `false`).

If `light` is true, add the class to the list of class names for the div (the [`classnames` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) is helpful here).

Add a onMouseOver function which sets the state of `light` to true.

Add a `useEffect` hook which depends on the value of `light`. Inside that hook, use `setTimeout` to change the state back to `false` after the time period.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const delay = setTimeout(() => {
      setHovered(false);
    }, 800);
    return () => clearTimeout(delay);
  }, []);

Comment: Does this looks something like it should?

Comment: That looks reasonable.

Comment: @Marty if this is the answer you're looking for, please accept it (Seems like you know how to do this ) so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 0):

holo, may you can check this?
and this is [online demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-s2gwpg?file=index.tsx)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      currentIndx: undefined,
      doms: Array.from({length: 10}).fill(1)
    };
  }

  handleMouse = (index: number) => {
    this.setState({
      currentIndx: index
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        currentIndx: undefined
      })
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const { doms, currentIndx } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
        <div>
          {doms.map((item, index) => (<div onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouse(index)} className={`square ${currentIndx === index ? 'light': ''}`} key={index}>{index}</div>))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be something like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ListItem = () => {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}
      className={`square ${hovered ? 'light' : ''}`}
    />
  );
}

const List = () => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
      <ListItem />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Square component first;

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Square.css";
export const Square = () => {
  const [light, setLight] = useState(false);
  const mouseOver = () => {
    setLight(!light);
  };
  return (
    <div onMouseOver={mouseOver} className={light ? "light" : null}>
      Square
    </div>
  );
};
export default Square;
```

Then on your page; import it and use it

```
import React from 'react'
    import './App.css'
    import Square from './components/Square'
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          {Array(3)
            .fill(' ')
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td className="space">
                    <Square />
                  </td>
                  <td className="space">
                    <Square />
                  </td>
                  <td className="space">
                    <Square />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
        </div>
      )
    }

export default App
```

When you mouseOver to the square component it will turn on red, if u do it again, className will be null so it will change back to normal color easy tutorial for you

```
CSS
.space{
  padding: 5px;
}
.light{
    color: red
}
```